# Rails 3.1 - Events Listings - How to handle events that span many dates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm building an events listing site. Currently each event is entered for a specific date and displayed in order......simple! However, I need to consider how to handle events such as festivals and plays that span more than one date. Entering the event over and over again for each date clearly isn't the best option. I've thought I could have a start date and end date, but i'm not sure how I would then make the event show in my index for the dates in between start/end. This is probably really simple, but I just thought i'd seek some guidance for those with more experience before I potentially set off down the wrong path with this.

The event schema at the moment:

```
create_table "events", :force => true do |t|
    t.date     "event_date"
    t.string   "headline"
    t.text     "info"
    t.integer  "event_type_id"
    t.integer  "venue_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "event_image_file_name"
    t.string   "event_image_content_type"
    t.integer  "event_image_file_size"
    t.datetime "event_image_updated_at"
    t.boolean  "free"
  end
```

And my Event Controller index does:

```
 @events = Event.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 12).find(:all, :conditions => ['event_date >= ?', Date.today], :order => "event_date")
```

**EDIT:**
I should have pointed out that i'm listing the events with a date header generated by the following line in my Event Controllers Index method:

```
@events_dates = @events.group_by { |e| e.event_date }
```

The the view is something along the lines of:

```
<% @events_dates.sort.each do |event_dates, events| %>
<div class="well">
<h3>
<% if event_dates == Date.today %>
Today
<% elsif event_dates == Date.today + 1 %>
Tomorrow
<% else %>
<%= event_dates.to_date.to_formatted_s(:my_format) %>
<% end %>
</h3>
</div>

<%= render events %>
<% end %>
```

The events partial then has the event headline, info etc.

So, I think what I need to do is alter the way I loop through my date headers. Instead of grouping event dates from the db and then looping those, I almost need to loop through calendar days and see if events occur on those dates based on event_start_date and event_end_date. Any ideas how to approach that?

Comment: "i'm not sure how I would then make the event show in my index for the dates in between start/end" - What do you mean by this? What do you want it to show? It looks like it's showing upcoming events presently. Do you want it to show all events that aren't finished? If so, use two fields, set start and end date to the same day for single day events, and change the condition to `end_date <= ?, Date.today` or something similar.

Comment: Also, find with a conditions hash is deprecated. You'll need to update your syntax for Rails 3 at some point.

Comment: Thanks for the conditions pointer....i'll update asap. To answer your first question; At the moment an upcoming event will display the event date, but say for example I have an event that occurs over the 1st to 3rd, how do I make my listing display "Event A - 2nd MM YYYY". I actually have grouped date headers so, i'd want it showing under 1st, 2nd & 3rd. Probably easy....i'll have a crack at using an end date!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a start and end date, using the conditions hash:

```
:conditions => ["event_start_date <= ? AND event_end_date >= ?", Date.today, Date.today]
```

Or arel:

```
.where("event_start_date <= ? AND event_end_date >= ?", Date.today, Date.today)
```

Edit:

Okay, so you want to iterate over a date range, and then display any events for that day. To iterate over a date range you'd use ruby's Date.upto() function, and for each date, you could then just iterate over the events, and only display events relevant for the current date.

The following code is assuming you've set up the @start_date and @end_date in the controller.

```
<% @start_date.upto(@end_date) do |date| %>
<div class="well">
<h3>
<% if date == Date.today %>
Today
<% elsif date == Date.today + 1 %>
Tomorrow
<% else %>
<%= date.to_formatted_s(:my_format) %>
<% end %>
</h3>
</div>

<%= render @events.select{|event| event.start_date < date && event.end_date > date} %>
<% end %>
```

There's a bit too much logic going on in the view here though, and you might have to do a little rejigging to get it to work, but it should get you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks, i'l have a go using this.

Comment: I've realised it's the way i'm producing the date headers that I need to work on so have posted an update to my question.

Comment: Nice, i'm going to try this now.

Comment: Seems to almost be working perfectly, except i'm getting an error on the great than in `event.end_date > date` , any idea why?

Comment: Ah, I think it's because not all of my events have and end_date defined!

Comment: Yes, that was it. Only change was `event.start_date <= date && event.end_date >= date` as without the equals, events on a single date weren't shown and first last dates of multi-date events also weren't show. Works like a treat now though. Thanks!!!

Comment: Nice one, glad you got it sorted! :)

Comment: Hey @cheeseweasel, i've noticed i'm getting some weird but kind of understandable results with the pagination. .paginate is being applied on @events, but I guess it also needs to be applied to the iteration of dates. Have simply tried `<% @start_date.upto(@end_date).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 12) do |date| %>` in my view but no such luck. Any thoughts on how to approach this? You can see the weird results at www.wozzoncornwall.co.uk/events , see page two starts with today,tomorrow etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to group by.

```
@events = Event.where('start_date >= ? AND end_date >= ?', Date.today.beginning_of_day], Date.today.beginning_of_day]).order(:start_date)
```

In your view do something like:

```
  Today
  <% for event in @events %>
    <% if event.start_date == Date.today %>
      <%= render "events/event" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end 
  Tomorrow
  <% for event in @events %>
    <% if event.start_date == Date.tomorrow %>
      <%= render "events/event" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Is that what your trying to achieve?

You'll need to clean it up a bit, perhaps using a `for event in @events.where date is today`, but you get the idea

Comment: hmm, after reading your question again, you may be trying to get more than just todays and tomorrows events?

Comment: Yes, I guess i'm essentially trying to create a calendar, but with a list view rather than the traditional table view. I would also prefer it if dates that don't have events are not shown. You can see the current view based on events with a single date here: http://www.wozzoncornwall.co.uk/events , I'd like to maintain this if possible?